# Cannot copy from Vim under Tmux into clipboard using "+p on Ubuntu

Tags: vim, zsh, tmux, clipboard

I'm using zsh, tmux, and Vim and for some reasons recently, I've noticed I cannot copy from Vim to X clipboard under tmux using "+y. Any idea how I can troubleshoot this issue? It used to work before.

Comment: What is the output of `:echo has('clipboard')`?

Comment: It returns 1. I think the problem is with tmux, using the wrong $DISPLAY env. I think I got this error, after I logged to my machine from my laptop using SSH. Here's more info on it: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75681/why-do-i-have-to-re-set-env-vars-in-tmux-when-i-re-attach

When I create a new tmux client, I can copy from Vim to clipboard, but I still can't get my detached client working, yet.

Comment: @mohi666 You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns 1. I think the problem is with tmux, using the wrong $DISPLAY env. I think I got this error, after I logged to my machine from my laptop using SSH. Here's more info on it: unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75681/… When I create a new tmux client, I can copy from Vim to clipboard, but I still can't get my detached client working, yet.

Comment: This is fixed by patches 7.4.523 and 7.4.558